# How to expire just one attribute in a session (Java)

Tags: java, spring, session

I am looking for a best solution on how to expire just one parameter in within the session in Spring. I have a session that expires in 3 hours, I need to add one parameter to it and expire it in 10 min.

ANy suggestions ?

Thank you

Comment: it's not clear what access to the expired param should produce. Exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a solution where all accesses to a session go through a component, which wraps your session and provides the expiry policy you want. This component could have a `session` scope.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I created component but not sure how to set expiration date.

@Component
@Scope(value = "session", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class SessionModel {